# Can I download a CSV file with `remote: true` on a Rails form?

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ajax, csv, ruby-on-rails-4

I'm building a very simple single-page Rails app with a single form using the `remote: true` option. Basically, the use selects a few options on the form, and I render a set of products matching these requirements back to the page using the `create.js.erb` view. So far, so good.

I'd also like to give the user the option to download a CSV list of the products. The problem is, with the `remote: true` option, I can't figure out how to actually trigger the download. I can use the hack [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23159911/override-the-respond-to-format-with-form-button-in-rails-3) to route to the correct format and action:

```
<%= button_tag( 'Download CSV', :value => 'csv', :name => 'format' ) %>
```

```
def create
  respond_to do |format|
    format.js
    format.csv { send_data @products.to_csv }
  end
end
```

This almost works; the correct CSV (text) data is returned in the browser response when I click the "Download CSV" button -- but it doesn't get rendered or trigger a file download, presumably because it's being returned in an AJAX response.

I could make this work by using a link, rather than submitting the form (assuming the action responds to 'GET'):

```
<%= link_to 'Download CSV', products_path(format: :csv) %>
```

But then I don't have access to the user data about the product requirements captured in the form parameters.

Is there any way to make this work, or do I need to lose the `remote: true` and submit the form via HTML (non-AJAX) to trigger the CSV download?

Comment: were you ever able to figure this out?

Comment: No, I'm using the `value: 'csv', name: 'format'` hack (with `send_data` in the controller). It works well enough but still smells.

Comment: I ended up appending the `Download CSV` as a `button_to` in the rendered `js.erb` partial.

Answer (score 1):

You can download the file in create.js.erb by using JavaScript code. 
First give an html a tag as hidden in your html.erb file.

```
<a id = "download_csv" hidden></a>
```

Then write the following code in create.js.erb to download the file:

```
var link = document.getElementById("download_csv");
link.href = '<%= j @filepath %>';
link.download = '<%= j @filename %>';
link.click();
```

Define @filepath and @filename in your controller.

Answer (score 0):

You can send a form as remote but return javascript that will open your download url.

```
def create
  respond_to do |format|
    format.js
  end
end
```

create.js.erb

```
window.open("<%= products_path(format: :csv) %>", "_blank")
```

This will open up a new tab to download the file then close it leaving the original page.

Comment: This issues a GET request to `products_path`, so does not actually submit the form with the parameters needed for the CSV generation.

Answer (score 0):

You can toggle off the AJAX submit of the form and use the `name="format"` hack to get it working.

On your CSV download button (a submit button), use `name="format"` and `value="csv"` and using javascript, remove the `data-remote="true"` from the form when the button is clicked.

On your regular submit button use `name="format"` and `value="js"` and using javascript, set `data-remote="true"` on the form when the button is clicked.

You'll need to either add `authenticity_token: true` to the form options or skip authenticity token verification on your controller action for the CSV submit to work.